# JIRA - How to find all parent tasks of sub tasks which are assigned to current user?

Tags: jira, jql

I have worked on several sub tasks in my project which has different parent tasks. I need a query to retrieve all the parent tasks of sub tasks which I have worked or working on? Is there a query in JQL(JIRA) for this task?

What are the plugins(free/licence) to improve these searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return all **parent tasks**, which have sub-tasks assigned to the current user. (The parent task need not be assigned to current user)

```
issueFunction in parentsOf("assignee = currentUser() ")
```

Comment: `issueFunction` requires the ScriptRunner plugin, which isn't free.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [Search Linked Issues](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.craftforge.jira.craftforge-jql-functions-plugin/server/overview) plugin (previously called Craftforge JQL Functions Plugin), which isn't free anymore, but it was until version 1.3.1, you can use this query:

```
issue in parentIssuesFromQuery("assignee = currentUser()")
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give you all the task other than sub task which is assigned to you

`assignee = currentUser() and type != Sub-task`

hope this will help