# JQL (Jira): Issues containing Sub-tasks assigned to me

Tags: jira, jql

How do I query issues that have `sub-tasks` assigned to me?

Resulting issues may or may not be assigned to me but they must contain `sub-tasks` within them which are assigned to me (`currentUser()`).

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839572/11640763

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JIRA - How to find all parent tasks of sub tasks which are assigned to current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839294/jira-how-to-find-all-parent-tasks-of-sub-tasks-which-are-assigned-to-current-u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
issueFunction in parentsOf("assignee = currentUser()")
```

This requires [Adaptavist Scriptrunner](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/index.html) to be installed.
You can find the documentation of further advanced JQL queries here: https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below JQL for getting all the sub-tasks assgined to you, even though the main task is assigned to someone else.

```
assignee = currentUser() AND type = Sub-task
```

The **Issue** link will be in the **Summary** field.

Summary field will be something like below
`Issue-1234 / Sub Task Summary`

Comment: nice try but i'm not really after the list of [sub-tasks], i want the list of [issues]

Comment: Well there is another approach then. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839572/11640763